# using mediawiki , how can I get random wikipedia page of a given quality?

Tags: mysql, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I'm using [Wikimedia random API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random) to get random article from Wikipedia, however, using this API I get completely random articles, the only parameter that I control here is rnnamespace which allow me to filter talk pages, user pages and so on.

I know that [some wikipedia pages are assessed for their quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Content_assessment#:%7E:text=WikiProject%20article%20quality%20grading%20scheme&text=The%20article%20has%20attained%20featured,from%20WP%3AFeatured%20article%20candidates.&text=Professional%2C%20outstanding%2C%20and%20thorough%3B,definitive%20source%20for%20encyclopedic%20information.), and I'd like to get a random article, for example, present only in the set of featured article. Is there a way I could use the API to do that ?

I was wondering if my only option was to make sql queries, even though ideally I could rely only on the API.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no proper API (the task for it is [T63840](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T63840)). Use [Special:RandomInCategory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:RandomInCategory) with the `Featured articles` category. Or https://randomincategory.toolforge.org/ for a slower but more mathematically correct alternative.

Comment: thank you, however I would not know how to use javascript or php to make a request to those websites in order to retrieve a random page title. I'm actually only interested in the title of a random page in a category. but I found a partly satisfying solution that I detailed in an answer below

Comment: Just make a web request to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory`, and read the `Location` header. It does pretty much the same thing you are describing in your answer, but you don't have to deal with things like API limits that way.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a partly satisfying solution. I can use the API [categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers), which return pages from a given category.

There's a parameter timestamps which allow to list all article from a specific date, so my idea is to choose randomly a date, then get a list of article from this date, and choose again randomly among those articles.

Of course, it does not guarantee an uniform distribution between the random choice of articles but it should work pretty good anyway.

I'll include my code later on to complete the answer.